# How do i/is it possible to run my Azure VM without running the RDP manually aka somewhere in the cloud?

Tags: azure, automation, virtual-machine

Rougly what im trying to do is:

1. Start VM automaticly(already doing this with Azure Automation)
2. Have the VM run an application(it already auto runs on startup) This is where the problem is, since the app runs fine when the VM is started manually with RDP, but is not run when the VM is started automaticly with Azure automation.
3. Stop VM (already doing this with Azure Automation)
4. All this must happend automaticly in the cloud so i dont have to do it manually trough the RDP sever application

i have an Azure VM that auto runs a console application on startup, this app do some work and then upload some files to my Azure storage. This console application needs to be run once a day, so im thinking that ill use the Azure Automation Account to auto start/stop it once every day, which i did and its working fine, atleast i can see the VM change status on the Azure portal at the specified times, however the files are not being pushed from my console application to my Azure storage when.

1. First question question is, do the Automation Account auto start of VM just make the VM avalible for use, and doesnt infact turn the OS on? 
   This would explain why the console application which should run auto on startup arent being run and therefor not pushing files.
2. Second question. If this is the case, how do i run my Azure VM without running the RDP manually aka somewhere in the cloud?

Normally it wouldnt be that big an issue for me to run the RDP myself once a day, but if i could automate it that would be ideal. Also when im traveling its not allways possible for me to get good enough internet access, and the VMs console application file pushing is vital for a website and a Xamarin Android app im managing, so its not something i can allow to "skip" sometimes whenever inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much wrong in this question that I don't even know where to start.

First of all, if you need to run something once a day, why not use Azure Automation, Azure Functions, etc?
Second, you cannot turn on VM but not turn on OS. how do you even suppose this might happen.

My thoughts - you configured your app to run on user login, not on startup, or the scheduled task doesn't run when the user is not logged in.

Comment: As im writing in my 3rd line i AM using Azure Automation. If i cannot Start the VM without booting the OS, it should mean that the OS are being started, in which case there is another reason the auto run on startup application arent run, which is so strange since its allways run just fine when using the RDP manually.
I dont want to do it with user login, since that would have to be manually done, and what im trying to do is make everything run by itself in the cloud wihtout my interference at all.

Comment: i'm asking why do you need a vm at all?

Comment: How else do this?
Sorry my ignorance but cloud computing is a rather new area of interest for me.

Comment: just use azure automation to do the same thing? or azure function? or logic apps?

Comment: Hmm Azure functions does look like a more ideal solution than a VM actually, thanks for the tip, ill go look into it right now! Cheers and have a nice weekend Mr. :)

Comment: i suggest you upvote\accept this answer in this case ;)